# How do I end my program when my while loop has met a certain condition?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am just taking an introduction course to computer science and we are looking at python right now. We just had to make a simple game for some practice. My problem is that when the player reaches $0 I want my while loop to end and the program to quit. My program just continues subtracting $5 past $0. I need help!!!

```
print ("Welcome to this game!")
password = input ("please put in $50 for 10 tries to play the game,"\
                      "then type ok.")
while password != ("ok"):
    password = input ("Sorry, wrong password. Please put in $50 for 10 tries to play the game,"\
                      "then type ok.")
    if password== ("ok"):
        print ("Time to play")

import random 
answer=random.randrange(50)+1

total=50

tries=1
guess=int(input("Guess the number and win $100: "))
while guess !=answer:
    print ("you loose $5")
    if guess < answer:
        print ("too low, you now have", total-5, "dollars left.")
    elif guess > answer:
        print ("too high, you now have", total-5, "dollars left.")
    guess=int(input("Guess the number and win $100: "))
    tries=tries+1
    total=total-5

print ("well done, you have won $100 in", tries,"tries")
```

Comment: `if total == 0: break;` or better `if total <= 0: break;`

Comment: also `while guess !=answer and total <=0:`

Comment: Use break keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [break](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) keyword will end the smallest enclosing loop.